# How to get PrintDialog to respond to choice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am printing a multi-line TextBox with the default printer.  I would like to offer a choice of printers by using the PrintDialog.  When I set it up, the PrintDialog appears and you select a printer, but when you press "Ok" it always goes to the default printer.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  I've included the appropriate code.

```
private void printTreeViewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //---added 6-29-12
    {
        textTreeView.Clear();

        CreateRowsFromNode(treeView1.Nodes[0], 0, "");

        //InitPrint(textTreeView.Text).Print();

        printDialog1.Document = InitPrint(textTreeView.Text);

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            InitPrint(textTreeView.Text).Print();
        }
    }
```

Originally there was no PrintDialog and it only called InitPrint(textTreeView.Text).Print().  The printDialog1 was added as shown above.

textTreeView is the TextBox to be printed.  Each line in the textTreeView textbox holds a node text value made with CreateRowsFromNode.

InitPrint looks like this:

```
string TextToPrint; //---added 6-29-12
    public PrintDocument InitPrint(string TextToPrint)
    {
        this.TextToPrint = TextToPrint;
        PrintDocument PD = new PrintDocument();
        PD.OriginAtMargins = true;
        PD.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; //---added 6-29-12
        PD.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        return PD;
    }


public void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) //---added 6-29-12
    {
        int Chars = 0;
        int Lines = 0;
        Font Font = new Font("Courier new", 9);
        //Font Font = new Font("Arial", 10);
        Rectangle R = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.MarginBounds.Size);
        StringFormat SF = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(TextToPrint, Font, R.Size, SF, out Chars, out Lines);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextToPrint, Font, Brushes.Black, R, SF);
        TextToPrint = TextToPrint.Substring(Chars);
        e.HasMorePages = (TextToPrint.Length > 0);
    }
```

The code that reads the TreeView into textTreeView is:

```
private void CreateRowsFromNode(TreeNode node, int level, string L = "") //---added 6-29-12
    {

        string data = "";
        string CurrentArrow = null;
        string NextArrow = "";

        //if root then no arrows needed
        if (node.Parent == null) {
            CurrentArrow = "";
            NextArrow = "";
        //if Not Last node of parent
        }
        else if (!(node.Parent.Nodes[node.Parent.Nodes.Count - 1] == node))
        {
            CurrentArrow = "├";

            NextArrow = "│";
        // is last node of parent
        } else {
            CurrentArrow = "└";
            NextArrow = " ";

        }
        //Add the next node to the TextBox
        if (node.Text.Length >= 115)
            textTreeView.Text = textTreeView.Text + L + CurrentArrow + node.Text.Substring(0,115) + vbNewLine;
        else
            textTreeView.Text = textTreeView.Text + L + CurrentArrow + node.Text + vbNewLine;

        //Add the Next Arrow to Left Part of string
        L = L + NextArrow;

        //Loop Through all its child nodes
        foreach (TreeNode nod in node.Nodes) {
            CreateRowsFromNode(nod, level + 1, L);
        }
    }
```

Comment: IMHO using `InitPrint(textTreeView.Text).Print();` you send the document to default printer...

Comment: The tags show for the post shows C# and VS only but is your app a windows form, wpf or what

Comment: Sorry HatSoft, yes, it is a windows form.

Comment: Marco, how can I get it to go to a chosen printer?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` option as in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx)

```
**PrintDialog.PrinterSettings - Specifies information about how a document is printed, including the printer that prints it, when printing from a Windows Forms application.**
```